# Creating square buffers with v.buffer in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, buffer

I do not seem able to create a square buffer around a point feature with v.buffer in GRASS GIS v.7.4.4.

The documentation states that "Using -s with a point vector map as input data, square buffers are created instead of round buffers." However, below is the command I ran, and the resulting buffer. Am I missing something obvious?

```
v.buffer -s input=vectmap type=point output=test_buffer distance=1000
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'problem' was encountered with GRASS 7.4.4 in Windows 10, but the option of  making square buffers around points by use of the -s flag was not included until GRASS 7.6, as per the release notes: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Grass7/NewFeatures76

The manual cited in the original question thus pertained to a newer version of GRASS than the one I was using, and I was indeed missing something obvious. Everything works fine with GRASS 7.6 in Windows 10.

Thanks for checking and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me. What operating system and which version of GRASS are you using?

```
micha@TP480$ v.buffer -s ims_stations_s type=point out=ims_buffers dist=1000
```

[image: square buffers]

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm again, it worked for me as well. Might worth double checking which version of GRASS you are using. I tried with GRASS 7.6.1 in Linux mint and Windows 10 with WGS 84 / UTM projection.

```
v.buffer -s --overwrite input=Points@PERMANENT output=square_buffer distance=100
```

[image: Square buffer]